# FastAPI and Websocket to post python Dataframe and read

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, websocket, fastapi

I am quite new to FastAPI and Websocket. It seems possible to post some Dataframe output to localhost and use it for another process. Currently, I am doing this using xlwings and this is slightly slower. Can someone advise how to achieve this using FastAPI and Websocket?

I have tried to follow the FastAPI documentation. But it is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel
import pandas as pd

app = FastAPI()

class DataFrameInput(BaseModel):
    # Define the structure of your
    # Dataframe input using Pydantic BaseModel
    data: pd.DataFrame

@app.post("/receive_dataframe")
async def receive_dataframe(dataframe_input: DataFrameInput):
    received_dataframe = dataframe_input.data
    # Process the received dataframe or save it for further use
    return JSONResponse(content={"message": "Dataframe received successfully"})
```